# Any way to exclude certain periods of weather data from multi-layers raster grid in R?

Tags: r, raster, data-manipulation

I have 16 years' daily mean temperature gridded data in `netCDF` format, the file size is quite big (about 3GB). Initially, I used `raster` package to load original gridded data in `RasterStack` object.

I am wondering how can I exclude weather data where its time ranges do not fall in my interest. More specifically, I want to use only 5 years weather data while here I have 15 years weather data instead. How can I operate this filtration for multi-layers raster data in R? For example, the time span of my original gridded data ranges from 1980.1.1 to 1995.12.31, and I want to only keep temperature data from 1980.1.1 to 1984.12.31. How can I filter out my wanted temperature grid from the multi-layers raster in R? Any possible idea to make this happen?

**reproducible example**:

```
r <- raster(xmn=5.75, xmx= 15, ymn = 47.25, ymx =55,res=c(0.25,0.25))
tempDat<- do.call(stack,lapply(1:5844,function(i) setValues(r,round(runif(n = ncell(r),min = -4,max = 23)))))
names(tempDat) <- paste0('X',gsub('-','.',ymd('1980.01.01') + days(1:5844)))
```

**Update**:

If there are other handy tools that can chunk `netCDF` file easily, I would like to know how to do it. Any fastest way to filter out my wanter daily mean temperature data from multi-layers raster grid will work for me. Thanks

**desired output**:

I only want to keep daily mean temperature data from 1980.1.1 to 1984.12.31; how can I make this happen? how can I operate this filtration on multi-layers raster grid in R? Any more thoughts? Thanks

Comment: You can use `subset`, e.g., `subset(tempDat, paste0('X', gsub('-', '.', ymd('1980.01.01') + days(1:10))))` to select 10 days.  Or is that not what you're after?

Comment: @d125q select the time ranges between `1980.1.1` and `1984.12.31`. Do you think your approach could work for very big dataset also (I mean subsetting). Plus, could you elaborate your solution by using above reproducible example data snippets? Thanks

Comment: Well, you can change `days(1:10)` in the example I provided to the amount of days you'd like to select and paste the code along with your sample in the console.  As for the size of the data set: I'm not sure, but I don't see why it wouldn't (and can't really think of a faster way).

Comment: @d125q I don't agree with you, yours is not efficient at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out my own way to answer this question:

So I used `raster::getZ()` to list out all date and `grep` to subset the time period that I am only interested in. Here is the solution:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

(tg <- brick("C:\\tn_0.25deg_reg_2018.nc"))
tg_date <- getZ(tg)  
grep("2018-01-01", tg_date)
grep("2018-05-31", tg_date)
```

## subset

```
tg_5months <- subset(tg, 1:150)
tg_5months @z$Date <- tg@z$Date[1:150]
```

and it is done nicely.